# How to make an embed division not take up a line of content

Tags: html

The following is my code, I am trying to make the embed division not take up a line of space because my goal is to make it next to my navigation menu and I was wondering how I should go about doing that? (The embed division is under H1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
  <link rel="icon" href="Images/favicon-16x16.png" type="image/png">
  <title>Web Portfolio: Patrick White's Index Page</title>
  <style>
     body {
     background-image: url("Images/Grass Background.jpg");
     background-color: #1D9842;
     color: #05173A;
     }
     a:link {
     color: #1E0442;
     }
     a:visited {
     color: #424A5A;
     }
     a:hover {
     color: #216A37;
     }
  </style></head>
   <body>
      <div>
     <a href="#main">Skip to main content</a>
  </div>
      <h1>Patrick White Web Portfolio</h1>
      <div align="right"><a href="http://www.gamesembedcode.com/2011/07/tennis-flash-game.html"></a>
        <embed src="http://www.freegaming.de/components/flash/7196382252.swf?affiliate_id=941efa0f97e566c4" quality="high" bgcolor="#e8ffff" width="480" height="480" name="7196382252.swf" menu="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></embed>
    </div>
      <div>
         <ul>
            <li>Patrick White</li>
        <li><a href="mailto:TotallyRealEmail@GOATS.com">TotallyRealEmail@GOATS.com</a></li>
            <li>843-653-3474</li>
        <li>link to one of my favourite <a href="http://eelslap.com/" target="_blank">websites</a></li>
        <li>If you like goats, download my presentation! In either: <a href="Images/GOATS.pdf" download>PDF</a>, <a href="Images/GOATS_VIDEO.wmv" download>Video</a>, <a href="Images/GOATS.odp">Open Office</a> or <a href="Images/GOATS.ppt">Microsoft Powerpoint</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
     <ul>
        <li>I.T. 9 (1-2)</li>
        <li>Mr. Gabriel Jones</li>
        <li>Web Design</li>
        <li><a href ="http://go.vsb.bc.ca/schools/pointgrey/Pages/Default.aspx" target="_blank">Point Grey Secondary</a>, 2016-2017</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
  <nav>
     <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Accesibility.html">Accessibility</a></li>
        <li><a href="Usability.html">Usability</a></li>
        <li><a href="Graphics.html">Graphics</a></li>
        <li><a href="JavaScript.html">JavaScript</a></li>
        <li><a href="Tools.html">Tools</a></li>
        <li><a href="Video.html">Video</a></li>
     </ul>
  </nav>
  <main id="main">
         <p>This web portfolio includes examples of my works in Mr. Jones' Web Design class. It also includes my reflections (below) in what I learned with each unit of the course.</p>
         <h2>Unit 2</h2>
     <p>In this section, I learned the basics of a fundamental scripting language for website design; <i>HTML5</i>. I learned about some of the many tags that are useful in the design of websites that will assist me in my prospective career in web design. In this unit I was presented with many resources to ensure that my HTML code was formatted correctly and was error-free, in the form of online generators. We also learned a great deal about how to incorporate links and images into our file, of which I found particularly interesting. In this section we learned a lot about how to input the actual content of our websites, and I am very excited for the future units in which we get to further design this content to seem visually appealing.</p>
     <h2>Unit 3</h2>
     <p>This section will be completed soon</p>
     <h2>Unit 4</h2>
     <p>This section will be completed soon</p>
     <h2>Unit 5</h2>
     <p>This section will be completed soon</p>
     <h2>Unit 6</h2>
     <p>This section will be completed soon</p>
     <h2>Unit 7</h2>
     <p>This section will be completed soon</p>
  </main>
  <form method="get" action="http://www.coolmath-games.com/0-me-and-the-key" target="blank">
     <button type="submit" style="background-color: #2A6D64; height:75px; width:400px;">Click to Play One of My Favourite Games!</button>
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please share your css too

Comment: oh sorry my CSS for this document is only for coloring and stuff so it doesn't actually apply to this particular circumstance. In hindsight I should not have included the CSS tag in this but I greatly appreciate your quick response!

Comment: your code is not working at all

Comment: That is a segment of the code, the other part bears no relevance but if it is easier should i just upload the full thing? Sorry I'm fairly new to this

Comment: Ok I have uploaded the full code

Comment: Well, there's no `align` attribute for a `div` element. You could use `float: right` in the CSS for that `div`... Might get you what you want, but it's a bit unclear.

Comment: Thank you so much @MikeMcCaughan! That did exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just add the floats and it will work .**

I have added classes  `LeftSection`  and `rightSection` to the `divs` with **float css**.

```
 .LeftSection {
      float: left;
    }

    .rightSection {
      float: right;
    }
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("Images/Grass Background.jpg");
  background-color: #1D9842;
  color: #05173A;
}

a:link {
  color: #1E0442;
}

a:visited {
  color: #424A5A;
}

a:hover {
  color: #216A37;
}

.LeftSection {
  float: left;
}

.rightSection {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#main">Skip to main content</a>
</div>
<h1>Patrick White Web Portfolio</h1>
<div align="right" class="rightSection">
  <a href="http://www.gamesembedcode.com/2011/07/tennis-flash-game.html"></a>
  <embed src="http://www.freegaming.de/components/flash/7196382252.swf?affiliate_id=941efa0f97e566c4" quality="high" bgcolor="#e8ffff" width="480" height="480" name="7196382252.swf" menu="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
</div>
<div class="LeftSection">
  <ul>
    <li>Patrick White</li>
    <li><a href="mailto:TotallyRealEmail@GOATS.com">TotallyRealEmail@GOATS.com</a></li>
    <li>843-653-3474</li>
    <li>link to one of my favourite <a href="http://eelslap.com/" target="_blank">websites</a></li>
    <li>If you like goats, download my presentation! In either: <a href="Images/GOATS.pdf" download>PDF</a>, <a href="Images/GOATS_VIDEO.wmv" download>Video</a>, <a href="Images/GOATS.odp">Open Office</a> or <a href="Images/GOATS.ppt">Microsoft Powerpoint</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>I.T. 9 (1-2)</li>
    <li>Mr. Gabriel Jones</li>
    <li>Web Design</li>
    <li><a href="http://go.vsb.bc.ca/schools/pointgrey/Pages/Default.aspx" target="_blank">Point Grey Secondary</a>, 2016-2017</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="Accesibility.html">Accessibility</a></li>
    <li><a href="Usability.html">Usability</a></li>
    <li><a href="Graphics.html">Graphics</a></li>
    <li><a href="JavaScript.html">JavaScript</a></li>
    <li><a href="Tools.html">Tools</a></li>
    <li><a href="Video.html">Video</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<main id="main">
  <p>This web portfolio includes examples of my works in Mr. Jones' Web Design class. It also includes my reflections (below) in what I learned with each unit of the course.</p>
  <h2>Unit 2</h2>
  <p>In this section, I learned the basics of a fundamental scripting language for website design; <i>HTML5</i>. I learned about some of the many tags that are useful in the design of websites that will assist me in my prospective career in web design. In
    this unit I was presented with many resources to ensure that my HTML code was formatted correctly and was error-free, in the form of online generators. We also learned a great deal about how to incorporate links and images into our file, of which
    I found particularly interesting. In this section we learned a lot about how to input the actual content of our websites, and I am very excited for the future units in which we get to further design this content to seem visually appealing.</p>
  <h2>Unit 3</h2>
  <p>This section will be completed soon</p>
  <h2>Unit 4</h2>
  <p>This section will be completed soon</p>
  <h2>Unit 5</h2>
  <p>This section will be completed soon</p>
  <h2>Unit 6</h2>
  <p>This section will be completed soon</p>
  <h2>Unit 7</h2>
  <p>This section will be completed soon</p>
</main>
<form method="get" action="http://www.coolmath-games.com/0-me-and-the-key" target="blank">
  <button type="submit" style="background-color: #2A6D64; height:75px; width:400px;">Click to Play One of My Favourite Games!</button>
</form>
```